# How to decode data of multiple rows in json and display in php tables using primary key date

Tags: php, mysql, json

```
date , 
details {
  "target1"  : "test1",
  "count1"   : "3",
  "remarks1" : "done",
  "target2"  : "test2",
  "count2"   : "3",
  "remarks2" : "done",
  "target3"  : "test3",
  "count3"   : "3",
  "remarks3" : "running"                            
}
```

Where date(pk) and details are two fields of a table. Display rows in tables of particular date.

Answer (score 0):

I dont really know what "php tables" are. But you probably need the functions [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php) and [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-merge.php).

For each row fetched from DB:

```php
$table[] = array_merge($row['id'], json_decode('details'))
```

Comment: i have used that and i have decoded it but its not able to decode multiple rows based on the dates..

Comment: i mean in html tables

Comment: Which MySQL-interface do you use in PHP? *mysql_*, *mysqli* or *PDO*?